# React Native - Unable to scroll till the bottom of my ScrollView

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, react-native-scrollview

I am using [react-native-nested-scroll-view](https://github.com/cesardeazevedo/react-native-nested-scroll-view) combined with react native's scrollview. On some android devices i am not able to scroll till the bottom of my app screen. The app screen is tabbed using react-navigation. The structure of my classes is like - 
Parent Class

```
    <View>
     <ScrollView>
      <ChildTabs/>
     </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

Child Tabs

```
<NestedScrollView>
 <Other Classes/>
</NestedScrollView>
```

When i scroll, my content is present but the app screen is not scrolling till the end. Some insight would be useful.
P.S. this behaviour is noted on some android devices. i am unable to figure out if it's a device specific bug or package related. Behaviour is same using flex or setting height for my scrollview or nesting the scrollview.

More code-
Parent.

```
  <View>
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0}}>
        <Gradient.MainGradient height={156}/>
      </View>
      <Reusables.Header style={styles.header} user={this.state.nameLabel} textStyle={styles.userName}/>
      <Text style={styles.settings}>Randoms</Text>
      <View style={{height:height-70}}>
        <SettingTabBar screenProps={this.showLoader} onNavigationStateChange={null}/>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
    {this.loader()}
  </View>
```

Child -

```
    <NestedScrollView style={{backgroundColor: '#f5f4f4',padding:10}}>
      <comp device={this.state.device} sendData={this.sendData}/>
      <comp showLoader={this.showLoader} deviceId=
      {this.state.device.idx} sendData={this.sendData}/>
      <Choices showLoader={this.showLoader}/>
      <Contacts did={this.state.device.idx} ref="emgContact"/>
      <map deviceId={this.state.device.idx}/>
    </NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Please share some more code

Comment: @ParasWatts Done.